# Instrumentation amplifier for high impedance on both inputs, why it is beneficial

Tags: impedance, instrumentation-amplifier

Instrumentation amplifier is a differential amplifier with two voltage followers before it. This solves the issue with that an op amp differential amplifier will provide a low impedance path through the resistors, and only have high impedance on one input.

In what way does the low impedance input, drawing current from the input, disturb the circuits measured so that it is better to use instrumentation amplifier that buffers or “copies” the signals first?